# Create a button that links to a html page for each item in database using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Im trying to create buttons for each item shown in a list from my database. currently i have the list displayed using Ajax to a PHP file.

More info: Currently this code pulls and lists all questions from a SQL database. for every value in the list the code displays it in the "DOM" div class. I would like to include a button that links to advice.html for every item in the list.

HTML:

```
    <body>
        <!--output of the json-->
        <div>
            <!--set the id to DOM to show output-->
            <div id="DOM">
            </div>

        </div>

        <a href="insert.html">insert</a>
        <a href="delete.html">delete</a>
        <a href="index.html">show data</a>
        <a href="login.html">login</a>
        <a href="register.html">register</a>

    </body>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/api/fetchdata.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "param=no",
            //on success it will call this function
            success: function (data) {
                var DOM = $('#DOM');
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    DOM.append("<h3>" + value.Subject + "</h3><p>" + value.Description + "</p>", $('<input type="button" href="localhost/advice.html" value="respond">')););
                });
                //if fail it will give this error
            }, error: function (e) {
                alert("failed to work");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific ??

Comment: I added to the DOM.append line.
DOM.append("<h3>" + value.Subject + "</h3><p>" + value.Description + "</p>", $('<input type="button" href="localhost/advice.html" value="respond">'));

But the button link doesnt work...

Comment: I would like to add a button for each item that appears in "DOM" div. all the buttons should link to the same HTML page. I would end up changing the content of the page.

Comment: So, presently the elements are getting appended properly but the button click is not working ?? Is this your problem ?

Comment: Yes, i just learned that you cannot use input types with append... so i attempted using the .after() method. This shows the buttons, but it shows them at the very bottom of the page out of order and does not link to the html page.

Comment: you can try the below answer and check if it is working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the line

```
DOM.append("<h3>" + value.Subject + "</h3><p>" + value.Description + "</p>", $('<input type="button" href="localhost/advice.html" value="respond">')););
```

can be replaced with

```
DOM.append("<h3>" + value.Subject + "</h3><p>" + value.Description + "</p>", $('<a href="localhost/advice.html"><button>respond</button></a>')););
```

Comment: Although i just realized that if its linking to an html page i wont be able to send data correlating to the question selected... i would need to send it to an PHP page. 
Ill make another question, thank you for the help!

Comment: what exactly you need to perform ?? I mean what you want to provide to the html page ??

Comment: I need to display the question picked from this page, and allow a user to respond to it. So you would click the "respond" button on this page, and then the other html page loads with that question and the ability to respond.

im unsure of how to use javascript to make a button for each item in "DOM" and send an identifier to an PHP page that allows me to focus in on that question.

Comment: so you want to display the question dynamically in html page which you redirect to ?? I mean do you want to load the page dynamically from php ??

Comment: I want to post the question which i would redirect to yes, and i want to be able to respond to the question (or give advice). I unsure if PHP is needed, or if i can easily do it using html. I believe that PHP will be needed to dynamically do so from php.

Comment: If so you want to load data dynamically from PHP. you can make a html form and include attributes such as questionID (the id of question you want to display) and some other required details. If you dont want to display them to user you can hide them with input type hidden Then write script in PHP to handle the above event. Finally use PHP header('location') to redirect the data to that html page

Comment: Also, this will be used for a mobile app using Cordova, which cannot just link directly to a php page... so i was on the right track on using HTMl. But how do i add data to follow with the button?

Comment: Then you can make a simple rest api that takes the request and makes the response data in JSON format. This even works for mobile apps. ( it work irrespective of backend language). If you get the success response data then you can make a redirect to some other page

Comment: I think what you previously said works better. Since i already have the string values stored in the .append, couldnt i just make an event handler that sends the data as a string to the html page and then on .ready state call a php page using ajax?